# javascript get className

Tags: javascript

Why does:

```
var isError = document.getElementById('companyName-element').getElementsByTagName('ul');
console.log(isError);
```

return `[ul.errors]` in firebug

whereas:

```
var isError = document.getElementById('companyName-element').getElementsByTagName('ul').className;
console.log(isError);
```

returns `'undefined'.`

Why doiesnt it return `'errors'`?

Comment: jQuery is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a (Node)list ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList)) of elements, even if there is just one or no match.

In your first code example, that list has one element and that is, what firebug shows to you.

In the second example you try to access a property `className` of the list (not the element!), which does not exist, thus returning `undefined`. If you want to access the `className` of that one element use the following:

```
var isError = document.getElementById('companyName-element').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className;
console.log(isError);
```

Note, that you might need to use a loop, if there are more than one elements returned.

Comment: @Quentin That's right, but for the sake of this problem, one can treat it like an array. I have corrected the answer, however.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements.

```
var isError = document.getElementById('companyName-element').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className;
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the result of getElementsByTagName is an array, so you'll need:

```
....getElementById('companyName-element').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className;
console.log(isError);
```

to get the first element in the array.

This is not researched or tested, however.

Comment: It is a node list, not an array.

Comment: like I said, unresearched. The solution should still work though.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var isError = document.getElementById('companyName-element').getElementsByTagName('ul').className;
    console.log(isError);
```

this should be replaced with

```
var isError = document.getElementById('companyName-element').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].className;
    console.log(isError);
```

as document.getElementsByTagName("ul") will give a nodelist